# Where to submit new mimetypes?

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop

I've defined new mimetypes with file suffix, where should I submit my work, so that it will be included in future linux/unix distros ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mine /etc/mime.types starts with:

```
# This file maps Internet media types to unique file extension(s). It is
# distributed in Arch Linux as the mime-types package, which is based on
# Gentoo's app-misc/mime-types package.
#
# The table below contains both registered and (common) unregistered types.
# A type that has no unique extension can be ignored -- they are listed
# here to guide configurations toward known types and to make it easier to
# identify "new" types. File extensions are also commonly used to indicate
# content languages and encodings, so choose them carefully.
#
# Internet media types should be registered as described in RFC 4288.
# The registry is at <http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/>.
```